# Heuristic: Daniell integral vs. Lebesgue integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, soft-question, lebesgue-integral

What are the advantages of the Daniel Integral over the Lebesgue integral and visa-versa?

Heuristically speaking, I was wondering why this axiomatic operator is less popular besides the fact that it is easier to introduce?

Comment: A similar question you might find useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175991/why-is-the-daniell-integral-not-so-popular